# Multiple kafka heartbeat failed messages during rebalance

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I have a Kafka application where the consumer is polling messages. Each message processing takes around 30-40 mins. I have tuned the following settings so that my consumer instance is not removed from the group, due to long processing of the message:

```
max.poll.interval.ms:3600000
max.poll.records = 1
```

But I'm still getting a lot of following rebalance messages in the log:

```
2022-07-04 12:17:54,168 INFO  thread=kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | periodicSync o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator:1054 : [Consumer clientId=consumer-periodicSync-5, groupId=periodicSync] Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing
 [Consumer clientId=consumer-periodicSync-5, groupId=periodicSync] Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing
```

Is there any other setting I need to do?  I'm getting a lot of messages like this frequently and I'm not sure how it might affect the working of the application.

Answer (score 0):

Session timeout between consumer and broker also plays a vital role here. Your consumer may be taking the default session.timeout.ms. Kindly adjust it accordingly.

### session.timeout.ms

The amount of time a consumer can be out of contact with the brokers while still
considered alive defaults to 3 seconds. If more than session.timeout.ms passes
without the consumer sending a heartbeat to the group coordinator, it is considered
dead and the group coordinator will trigger a rebalance of the consumer group to
allocate partitions from the dead consumer to the other consumers in the group. This
property is closely related to heartbeat.interval.ms. heartbeat.interval.ms con‐
trols how frequently the KafkaConsumer poll() method will send a heartbeat to the
group coordinator, whereas session.timeout.ms controls how long a consumer can
go without sending a heartbeat. Therefore, those two properties are typically modi‐
fied together—heatbeat.interval.ms must be lower than session.timeout.ms, and
is usually set to one-third of the timeout value. So if session.timeout.ms is 3 sec‐
onds, heartbeat.interval.ms should be 1 second. Setting session.timeout.ms
lower than the default will allow consumer groups to detect and recover from failure
sooner, but may also cause unwanted rebalances as a result of consumers taking
longer to complete the poll loop or garbage collection. Setting session.timeout.ms
higher will reduce the chance of accidental rebalance, but also means it will take
longer to detect a real failure.